# Adding images with CSV import

Tags: magento-1, import, image, csv, export

I have been running into problem after problem with the CSV export/import functions. My currently problem is that I cannot seem to assign 'image', 'small_image', and 'thumbnail' attributes to any image path.

This even fails:

1. I manually change the image, small_image, and thumbnail of a product to one of the images associated with the product, and save.
2. I export my product CSV.
3. I check to see if those attribute fields are filled in for that product, and they are.
4. I import the CSV using the CSV import tool, using the 'Replace Existing Complex Data'.
5. I check the product that I changed, and it is now not showing any assignment for image, small_image, or thumbnail.

If my understanding is correct, a CSV that is exported and unchanged should be importable to yield the exact same product data, yes? What's going on here?

Comment: I am running Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Comment: You must put the images into the folder media/import/ otherwise nothing happens

Comment: I cannot reference the files in the /[first letter]/[second letter]/[full file] format if they are already there? This way appears to add the images to the product using _media_images just fine. Are you saying that I have to re-import the images in order to reference these files in their final location? Is there no way I can assign images already associated with the product via _media_images the image, small_image, and thumbnail attributes?

Comment: Read this document done from a friend of mine about import. Go to the product image chapter. http://www.avs-webentwicklung.de/fileadmin/documents/20120512_Produktimport_ImportExport_eng.pdf

Comment: No you cannot do the reference to an existing picture. You have to import again. But it makes no sense to re-import into the same products, the same images. Remove them from the CSV import file otherwise add new one and set the images into `/media/import/`

Comment: im having problems despite following the instructions for magento 1.9.2.2 what am i doing wrong? my images are in the import folder
/images/t/50b51bfa4f8a5/primary.jpg i even tried putting it in the /media/catalog/product folder and no cigar could the filepath like that cause a problem? i really can't change it because its from a different site to this magento site... damn

Comment: This may be obvious, but do ensure your image file name does not contain any special characters.

Comment: i got error using what you suggested,

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BLkyu0n.png

Comment: my xl formate ..

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0Q4w3Vb.png

Answer (score 15):

First you have to upload alll the images you want to import in the `media/import/yourimagesfolder/`

The in the CSV columns for image, thumbnail and small_image your image path should look like this

`/yourimagefolder/imagename.jpg`

Answer (score 9):

First, unfortunately Magento doesn't import the files generated by it's export. AFAIK, this is true for both import/export module and default out-of-box dataflow profiles.

Second, I'll try to bring more light on images question as I see for many it's unclear how it works:

1. When you import, it expects that images are placed in `media/import`.
   So if you have a value in csv **image** = "/a/b/c.jpg", it will look for it in `media/import/a/b/c.jpg` - and if it won't find, it will not import image.
2. When you export, it doesn't do anything with your images, just generated CSV with populated values. So it generates the images path respectively to your `media/catalog/product` folder. If you try to import them unless you copied them to `media/import` folder.

---

If you looking for way to bulk download/upload the products with their images and consider paid modules.
During export, it copies media files to the folder where it expects to see it during import, so you never get the situation that your images were missed during export/import etc. After export, you can download the folder with all the copied products images and simply re-import it into another website.

Comment: so is it `var/media/import` or `media/import` ?

Comment: it's media/import

Answer (score 4):

You must have to specify the **_media_attribute_id** and **_media_image** attribute. Without using these two attributes, you cannot import images properly. So the right CSV format for images import is as follow:

```
sku, image, image_label, small_image, small_image_label, thumbnail, thumbnail_label,_media_image,_media_attribute_id,_media_is_disabled,_media_position,_media_lable
```

[Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r_0c_P3tX48o5gsR2Lj3y_-ez02UVZS_u-8PkuhFRwc/edit?usp=sharing) to see the right csv file for Images import

*Note: Make sure the images are placed in the magento_root/media/import/ folder. Otherwise Magento could not Import the images.*

For more information, visit this [link](http://rltsquare.com/blog/?p=170)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it without purchasing an extension.
After exporting the products, I deleted the columns for image, small image and thumbnail.
after editing as required, i imported and appended complex data. so i only replaced data for the information i needed.

anyway. worked for me. for new products, i had to upload the images to the import folder and reference the image and it worked too.