# Is there a way to automatically upload pictures with bar-code (EAN) in it's name to products with those EAN codes

Tags: import

Okay guys,

I imported a .csv file with products information to a certain categorz in magento. And since I'm moving those products from an old website I have HUGE (30k) pictures folder taken from and old website database that should be tied with already imported products.

All of the pictures have EAN code names so one picture would have a name 3165140001809 and that number is also EAN code of it's respective product. If a product had several pictures name of other pictures would be 3165140001809(1);(2)... at the end.

I hope you could understand :3

Comment: Are you using a custom script to import these CSV files? Or do you use one of the native Magento importers? And which one do you use?

Comment: I used plain Magento import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can import an image to Magento using the default import methods is by adding a column to your CSV file with the file name in it. So what you could do is just copy the EAN column and add a suffix .jpg.

Here is an older post about importing images in Magento: [Adding images with CSV import](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/adding-images-with-csv-import)