# How can i solve image import not working after hosting its good working in localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, error, image, importexport

Am not able to import image into my site, before am using localhost working good, after hosting not Working.

Magento version : 1.9.2.3

Note : After i import i got positive response in Admin, right after check into back end its not saved.

[image]

My image path :

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand...is this the product image? Were are you importing this in Magento?

Comment: Yes, image importing not working

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Where are you importing this? Could you post specifically? For example: I go to Catalog > Manage Products > Open a specific product, etc...

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro : could you pls see this about what you asked.

Comment: Oh OK, so that's different. This is not IMAGE importing, this is PRODUCT importing. So you are not importing image files, you are importing the database of your products. Are the products showing after the import? I mean, if you go to Catalog > Manage Products, are you able to see the name, description and other information about the products you are importing?

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro :    this is image importing, above ae images, how can i solve this

Comment: set file permission 777 to media/ folder and then try

Comment: i also did, not working

Comment: it seems your image path is not proper, make sure image path is proper or not.

Comment: @JaiminParikh    How can i check it

Comment: refer @ http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/dataflow.html , it seems you have added path like /5/2/52503855.jpg in import file and on server you have added images directly in media/import folder.

Answer (score 2):

As Its all working fine on localhost then lets try

1. check the host it have the gd extension installed?
2. check  hosting have all things required for magento using
   https://gist.github.com/atomicpages/4383809
3. After this check permissions of magento dir var , media and app/etc

   find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

   find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

   chmod +x mage
4. Also Disable cache and re-index database once

Then follow the other solutions as you already able to import correctly in localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `media/import/` is where you will upload images to, then reference the filename and directories in your CSV file.  examples:

- 1) myproduct.jpg
- 2) subdir/mysecondproduct.jpg

1) Uploading the above files & folders to the root of your Magento installation under media/import.

`<Magento-root-directory>/media/import/myproduct.jpg`

your CSV reference for the image would be simply: `myproduct.jpg`.

2) For the second example it after uploading to

`<Magento-root-directory>/media/import/subdir/mysecondproduct.jpg`

your CSV reference for the image would be: `subdir/mysecondproduct.jpg`

I've made a video awhile back which may help demystify the issues you are having:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoqPVz8Fq7o

Also Related:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16939/69
- http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/dataflow.html

Be sure that the webserver user / group it is running as.

Connect to your server via SSH, then see: `top` command or review your webservers configuration to determine which group is accessible, if not `chmod -R 777 media/` in your Magento root directory may help as well.

Comment: not working what you suggested, am using magmi its working

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the permission of **all images of media/import** permission from 644 to 755 as images can not move with 644 permission. This will work only if it is working on your local system.

```
chmod -R 755 media/import/*
```